# Audio visualization

Tags: python, audio, pygame

So I am attempting to make a little audio player using Pygame. I wanted to add a little audio visualizer similar to in Windows Media Player. I was thinking of starting with an audio wave that scrolls across the screen. But I'm not sure where to start.

Right now I'm just using pygame.mixer to start, stop, and pause the music. I think I would have to use pygame.sndarray and get some samples but I don't know what to do from there. What can I do to turn those samples into a visual audio wave?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the pygame.draw methods.

You can probably take the audio values and map them to one of the draw options - like draw.arc or draw.line. You will have to map the signal output to values that remain within the X and Y max and min of the viewport.

Processing can do the same thing, but is a bit easier to implement if you are interested in learning the scripting language. It has methods specifically for doing the mapping for you and you can do some pretty extreme visuals without a lot of code.

Comment: How to get the audio values?